# How can I select two lists from a list of lists so that I receive the system of equations has only rational solutions?

Tags: equation-solving

I want to make a sytem of equations has the form
$$\begin{cases}
a_1x^2+b_1y^2 + c_1xy+d_1x + e_1y+3=0,\\
a_2x^2+b_2y^2 + c_2xy+d_2x + e_2y+3=0.
\end{cases}$$
so that the given system of equations has always two solutions $(1,2)$ and $(3,4)$. I tried

```
f[x_, y_] := a*x^2 + b*y^2 + c*x*y + d x + e y + 3
l = {a, b, c, d, e} /. 
Solve[{f[1, 2] == 0, f[3, 4] == 0, 1 <= a <= 10, 
1 <= b <= 10, -10 <= c <= 10, -10 <= d <= 10}, {a, b, c, d, e}, 
Integers]
```

Now, I want to select two lists in list `l` and make system of equations. For example

```
u = l[[77]];
v = l[[75]];
w = {x^2, y^2, x y, x, y};
Reduce[{u.w + 3 == 0, v.w + 3 == 0}, {x, y}, Reals]
```

> (x == 3/10 && y == 3/5) || (x == 1 && y == 2) || (x == 3 && 
>          y == 4) || (x == 25/4 && y == 4)

Another system of equations

```
u = l[[3]];
v = l[[12]];
w = {x^2, y^2, x y, x, y};
Reduce[{u.w + 3 == 0, v.w + 3 == 0}, {x, y}, Reals]
```

> (x == -15 && y == -6) || (x == 1 && y == 2) || (x == 3 && y == 4)

In the above system of equations, the equation `u.w + 3==0` can be factor

```
Factor[u.w + 3]
```

> (3 + x - 2 y) (1 + x - y)

Now, I consider system of equations

```
u = l[[8]];
v = l[[75]];
w = {x^2, y^2, x y, x, y};
Solve[{u.w + 3 == 0, v.w + 3 == 0}, {x, y}, Reals]
```

> {{x -> 1, y -> 2}, {x -> 3, y -> 4}, {x -> 3/49 (16 - Sqrt[109]), 
>     y -> -(11/4) + 85/98 (16 - Sqrt[109]) - (437 (16 - Sqrt[109])^2)/
>       9604 + (3 (16 - Sqrt[109])^3)/4802}, {x -> 3/49 (16 + Sqrt[109]), 
>     y -> -(11/4) + 85/98 (16 + Sqrt[109]) - (437 (16 + Sqrt[109])^2)/
>       9604 + (3 (16 + Sqrt[109])^3)/4802}}

How can I select two list from the list `l` so that I receive a system of equations in which all of them can't factor and the system of equations has only rational solutions?

Answer (score 1):

```
Select[Subsets[l,{2}],
       IrreduciblePolynomialQ[#[[1]].w+3] &&
       IrreduciblePolynomialQ[#[[2]].w+3] &&
       VectorQ[{x,y}/.Solve[{#[[1]].w+3==0,#[[2]].w+3==0},{x,y},Reals],
               VectorQ[#,(#\[Element]Rationals)&]&]&]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to generate "some" integer solutions:

```
p1 = {1, 2};
p2 = {3, 4};
f[x_, y_] := a*x^2 + b*y^2 + c*x*y + d x + e y + 3
g[r_, s_, t_, u_, v_, x_, y_] := 
  f[x, y] /. {a -> r, b -> s, c -> t, d -> u, e -> v};
{n, p, q} = 
  Normal@CoefficientArrays[f[x, y], {x, y}, "Symmetric" -> True];
sol = First@
  Solve[{{1, 2}.q.{1, 2} + p.{1, 2} + n == 
     0, {3, 4}.q.{3, 4} + p.{3, 4} + n == 0}, {a, b, c, d, e}]
csol[u_, v_, 
  w_] := ({u, v, w, d, e} /. sol) /. {a -> u, b -> v, c -> w}
func[] := With[{r = csol @@ RandomInteger[{-10, 10}, 3]},
  ContourPlot[g[##, x, y] & @@ r == 0, {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5},
   Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.04], Point[{p1, p2}]}, 
   PlotLabel -> Style[Column[{r,
       g[##, x, y] & @@ r}], 8]]]
```

The quadratic form was completely unneccessary.

9 "random" integer triples:

[image]